# split columns and name them using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split a column into 3 based on a delimiter `":"` and I am able to do
that using the code below.  But now want to change the names of the split
columns from the default of 1,2,3,4.  Please advice how I can do that.

```
from pandas import *
df = DataFrame(
     {'CustomerName' : ["Paul", "John"], 'Seatblocks' : ["2:218:10:4,6","2:218:10:4,6"]}); 
df

df.join(df.Seatblocks.apply(lambda x: Series(x.split(':'))))
```

Answer (score 3):

People have already given the `rename` approach, but I find these things are easier if you avoid the temptation to cram everything into one line.  Once you have a frame, you can simply assign to `.columns`:

```
>>> sb = df.Seatblocks.str.split(":").apply(pd.Series)
>>> sb.columns = ["a", "Three Digit", "??", "coord"]
>>> pd.concat([df, sb], axis=1)
  CustomerName    Seatblocks  a Three Digit  ?? coord
0         Paul  2:218:10:4,6  2         218  10   4,6
1         John  2:218:10:4,6  2         218  10   4,6
```

The first line is simply a version of your `(df.Seatblocks.apply(lambda x: Series(x.split(':'))))` which takes advantage of the vectorized string operation accessor `.str` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods)).

Answer (score 2):

Just [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas.DataFrame.rename) them:

```
df.rename(columns={0:'col_1', 1:'col_2', 2:'col_3', 3:'col_4'},inplace=True)
```

A more obscure method is to form a union of the new names to the first 2 elements of your columns and assign directly:

```
In [14]:

df.columns = df.columns[:2] | pd.Index(['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4'])
df
Out[14]:
  CustomerName    Seatblocks col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4
0         Paul  2:218:10:4,6     2   218    10   4,6
1         John  2:218:10:4,6     2   218    10   4,6
```

Answer (score 1):

Columns were renamed to A, B, C, D.

```
from pandas import *
df = DataFrame(
     {'CustomerName' : ["Paul", "John"], 'Seatblocks' : ["2:218:10:4,6","2:218:10:4,6"]}); 
df = df.join(df.Seatblocks.apply(lambda x: Series(x.split(':'))))
df.rename(columns={0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'}, inplace=True)
df
```

Answer (score 1):

### This may help:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
     {'CustomerName' : ["Paul", "John"], 'Seatblocks' : ["2:218:10:4,6","2:218:10:4,6"]}); 
#df
#1.split, rename
df_extraction = df['Seatblocks'].str.split(':', expand=True)
df_extraction.columns = ['seatBlock'+str(i) for i in df_extraction.columns]

# 2.merge extracted to df
df = pd.concat([df, df_extraction], axis=1)
df

CustomerName    Seatblocks  seatBlock0  seatBlock1  seatBlock2  seatBlock3
0   Paul    2:218:10:4,6    2   218     10  4,6
1   John    2:218:10:4,6    2   218     10  4,6
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `df.column` to get the new column names

```
In [1]: from pandas import *

In [2]: df = DataFrame(
   ...:      {'CustomerName' : ["Paul", "John"], 'Seatblocks' : ["2:218:10:4,6","2:218:10:4,6"]}); 

In [3]: df2 = df.join(df.Seatblocks.apply(lambda x: Series(x.split(':'))))

In [4]: names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'booz']

In [5]: df2.columns = [x if str(x).isalpha() else names.pop() for x in df2.columns]

In [6]: df2.columns                                              
Out[6]: Index([u'CustomerName', u'Seatblocks', u'booz', u'baz', u'bar', u'foo'], dtype='object')

In [7]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small function for automatically adding column names

```
def col_splitter(df, orig_col, deli):
    #Split the column on the delimiter provided
    splitted=df[orig_col].str.split(deli, expand=True)
    
    # make a dictionary of new column names based on the number of splits
    col_names={k:f'{orig_col}_{k}' for k in splitted.columns.values}

    # Lastly, rename columns ==> 0:'Seatblocks_0', 1:'Seatblocks_1' etc
    splitted.rename(columns=col_names,inplace=True)
    return splitted



col_splitter(df,'Seatblocks',':')
```